# Why does Ubuntu keep adding additional Ubuntu operating system choices to the Grub?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, boot, grub

When I startup my machine, the Grub (Grub2 - Karmic) starts and asks if I want to run Windows or Ubuntu. But there are 6 different choices for Ubuntu and they are all the same. Plus, when I started up today I had one more - I don't know how it got added?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you actively update the system?

The entries are probably not the **exact** same, but appear similar. If you look closely, the last few numbers are probably different:

[image]

You will see it changes after groups of 2. Each boot entry in Ubuntu has 2 modes by default -- regular multi-user mode and recovery mode. When you update the kernel, I believe the old entries remain in `grub.cfg` so you can boot into older kernels if you are having trouble with an upgraded one. You can remove them by editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Ubuntu system updates which update the kernel. GRUB apparently allows you to boot into different versions of the kernel, hence the different entries.

Answer (score 0):

Are there 100% the same? If not that is probably normal (at last in Ubuntu). Those are different kernels versions. They are added during system (kernel) updates.

One old entry would be useful if You you had to fall back to older version if new kernel is working wrong and You cant boot. You can safety remove other entries.

Comment: You mean:  "you had to fall back"?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have installed new kernels when upgrading, and two startup actions are installed per every new kernel.
The easiest way to solve this, is to uninstall all old kernels. I would recommend you installing the GUI program [ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), to do this.